# Leaflet Error 'Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string'

Tags: php

So I was trying out this code and keeps getting this error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Function name must be a string in
>   /var/www/public_html/admin/get-features.php:10 Stack trace: #0 {main}
>   thrown in /var/www/public_html/admin/get-features.php on line 10

You can see my code below

I have tried Googling and trying different things I found on google but cant seem to get it working

```php
<?php
$conn = new PDO('mysql:host=;dbname=;charset=utf8','','',array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8'));
$rs = $conn->query('SELECT *, x AS x, y AS y FROM GPS');
if (!$rs) { /* handle error */ }
$geojson = array ('type'  => 'FeatureCollection','features'  => array());
while ($row = $rs->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $properties = $row;
    unset($properties['x']);
    unset($properties['y']);
    $array_push($geojson['features'], array(
        'type'  => 'Feature',
        'geometry' => array(
            'type' => 'Point',
            'coordinates' => array($row['x'],$row['y']) ),
        'properties' => $properties )
    );
}

header('Content-Type: text/json');
echo JSON_encode($geojson);
?>
```

Comment: Shouldn't `$array_push(` be `array_push(`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the **$** in front of array_push.